# Milk alternative in pancake batter

Tags: substitutions, milk, pancakes, dairy

What could I use in place of milk in [pancake batter](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/basicpancakeswithsuga_66226)?  Would rice milk or soya milk work?  What about in [scotch pancakes](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/4095/scotch-pancakes-with-banana-and-maple-syrup)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Soy milk works great in pancakes. My basic recipe for pancakes is about a cup of flour, about a cup of soy milk, a tablespoon or two of sugar and veg oil, and a few teaspoons of baking powder. Works great, makes nice, fluffy pancakes. (I know, not a "recipe" so much as list of ingredients with approximate proportions, but that's how I tend to cook, experimenting and learning from experience as I go...)

Edit: I don't know about scotch pancakes; I've never made them, but upon looking up a couple recipes, I don't see why it wouldn't... Soy milk behaves much like milk in these kinds of recipes, the only difference being that soya adds a bit of binding that dairy milk doesn't (and perhaps a smidge of a taste difference?)

Edit2: Haha, ok, so my "pancakes" are much more like your "scotch pancakes" -- there is such a wide spectrum of "pancakes", from crepe-y types to big, fluffy types... So then, yes, I'd say soya'd certainly work fine for scotch pancakes; for your "pancakes", I still suspect it'd be alright. With crepes mainly you just need liquid (hence the mixing with water in your posted recipe) -- the milk is mainly for some added flavour; I'd conjure that soya would work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I often use coconut milk or cream in my pancakes and it's delicious. Sometimes rice milk, but it does have a bit of a tendancy to stick. Ok if you're using teflon I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

Just use water... it's that simple.

Comment: This only works if you are prepared to take large differences in taste and texture from traditional pancakes, and if you use a backing-powder-only recipe

Comment: This would work if making pancakes from a boxed mix, actually. But since the OP linked to a from-scratch pancake recipe, this _wouldn't_ work for their application.